# awk dictionary not storing value

Tags: awk

I have written an awk statement, and the "a" dictionary is not storing values properly for an unknown reason.

I have the following file:

```
cat lookup.txt 
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

However when I write the following awk statement the "a" dictionary seems not to be storing values properly:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;print a[$2];print $2}' lookup.txt 

a

b

c
```

I would expect that statement to print as follows:

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do `a[$1]=` and then `a[$2]`, there is no `a["a"]`, there is `a["1"]`

Comment: @KamilCuk can you clarify your comment? Are you suggesting my statement should be ... `a[$1]=a[$2]`...?

Comment: In other words, **change** `print a[$2]` **to** `print a[$1]`, e.g. there are no `a[a, b, c]` indexes, you have `a[1, 2, 3]` indexes...

Comment: If it's still not clear what the issue is, run `awk '{ a[$1]=$2; printf "$1=%s, $2=%s\n", $1, $2 } END{ for (i in a) printf "a[%s]=%s\n", i, a[i] }' lookup.txt` to show you the values of every $1 and $2 and the indices and values stored in the array then ask yourself "what is the valued of `a[$2]` for any of the $2s from my input?".

Comment: What your code is doing is the equivalent of `a[17]="foo"; print a["foo"]` instead of `a[17]="foo"; print a[17]`.

Answer (score 0):

You store a[$1] but fetch a[$2]. When the program ends, the a array contains three records: a["1"] = "a", a["2"] = "b", and a["3"] = "c". When you fetch from the array, there are no elements a["a"], a["b"] and a["c"], so those values are printed as nulls. I think you probably want to print a[$1].

Comment: I'm trying to use this as a lookup table so that I can replace values in a 2nd file such that if a column in the second file contains `a[$1]`, that column's value will be replaced with `a[$2]`. This type of operation has been addressed elsewhere, but I couldn't get those solutions to work because the dynamics in this thread here aren't working as expected.

Comment: A couple of people have already explained the issue to you (@KamilCuk in a comment and then here in an answer), just **think** about what they're saying. There's no magic, nothing fancy or complicated happening here - you're simply populating an array using 1 set of indices (1,2,3) but then trying to access the values stored in the array using a different set of indices (a,b,c).

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton I have seen this sort of notation in other threads: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2=a[$2]}1' lookup.txt data.txt`. I'm wondering why I am unable to implement something similar.

Comment: Again, just **think** about what that code does, it's not doing what the code in your question is doing. You have to understand that the `$2` values from 1 file aren't necessarily the same values as `$2` from a different file and you need to access the array by the **values** of its indices. To help you understand it, add `print` statements to your code to dump the $1s, $2s, array indices, and array values so you can see those as the array is being populated and accessed.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to say NR==FNR. It contributes nothing to the program.

Comment: @user448810 my impression is that the OP found a script that does X and is trying to shuffle the parts of it around to do Y by trial and error without first learning what any of those parts (`NR==FNR`, `a[$1]=$2`, `a[$2]`) actually do.